# Cannot run Dota 2 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: games, steam, opengl

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit on my laptop and now I cannot run Dota 2. glxinfo says that I have OpenGL 2.1:

```
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 10.3.2
```

When I click Play Dota 2 in Steam and it says:

```
Failed to create OpenGL context. Your graphics card must support at least OpenGL 3.1!
```

I played Dota 2 on Windows 7 64 bit without any errors.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to upgrade your version of OpenGL. Try running `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade` followed by `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and `sudo apt-get autoremove`.

Comment: Also, please provide your system's specs. And are you running  a proprietary GPU driver, or an open-source one?

Comment: How can I discover what driver I am using?